# Limiting options for generic type in a custom NativeActivity<T>

Tags: generics, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Is there a way to limit and/or alter the options presented to the user by the generic type picker when adding a generic activity to a workflow?

We are embedding dynamic workflow support into our application, and I'm building a set of custom activities to read values from the associated business objects into workflow variables. So, now we have activities like `ReadDocumentProperty<T>` and `SetItemProperty<T>`

These business objects contain user-defined property sets that can only be one of a handful of fundamental types (integer, float, string, boolean, datetime, or list), so it makes no sense to expose the entire set of .NET types to the customer to pick from. Even worse, the one they are most likely to **want** is System.Double (for invoice amounts, etc) and that's not even in the default list.

Is there any way to change this prompt: replace it, filter it, pre-populate the defaults, etc., and still be able to use a generic custom activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New day, new ideas. I truly forgot this one.

If you want validation at design time, it's totally possible to do something like this:

```
public sealed class MyActivity<T> : NativeActivity<T>
    {
        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);

            if (typeof(T) != typeof(int) &&
                typeof(T) != typeof(bool) &&
                typeof(T) != typeof(DateTime) &&
                typeof(T) != typeof(decimal) &&
                typeof(T) != typeof(string))
            {
                metadata.AddValidationError(
                    "Generic must be 'int', 'DateTime', 'decimal' or 'string'");
            }
        }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Execution logic 
        }
    }
```

This is perfectly acceptable if you're making activities available for a client to design it's own workflow. But keep in mind that **this is design-time validation**. If someone uses your activity through code it will compile perfectly but it will thrown a validation exception when validated/executed at runtime.

---

The only way to constraint a type on a generic activity is with `where` keyword, just like you were using any other [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

Regarding the *Select Generic Types* dialog, if you do something like this:

```
public sealed ReadDocumentProperty<T> : CodeActivity<T>
    where T : struct
{
    //...
}
```

The dialog will filter all types but `struct`. Maybe that way *System.Double* appears at the default list, although that's just a guess (haven't test it) and of course you can't rely on it. Moreover, if you select a type, for the first time, that it isn't on the default list, second time it will appear on it.

**Edit**:

For what I can understand this guy found a way to "*[reduce the "browse for types" list](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/0a306b08-36d5-447a-a18f-954f44cd55f0)*" although he uses reflection and is nowhere near a linear, direct or documented way of doing it. For what I can see it reduces the list for the all editor and not on a specific activity (counting that you're using the rehosted editor, otherwise forget this)

Comment: I thought about constraining the generic type but I don't think there's a constraint that matches what I want (basically just int, bool, DateTime, decimal, and string)

Comment: You're right. That's a god damn C#'s limitation. Anyway, check my edit and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, I read that, and I agree that it's not linear, direct, or even apparently supported :) I went a different way, I just ended up making concrete classes for the handful of types I wanted. There doesn't appear to be any "proper" way to change that generic type picker.

Comment: Sorry you mean the edit up top not the bottom :) Yes, that helps a bit, but not quite enough for me. I was trying to make the designer experience more convenient for the end user who is used to our dumbed-down type terms (e.g. we say "Whole Number", "Number", and "True Or False" instead of int, double, and bool.) I'll mark yours as answered, tho, since it did partly answer my question :)